# Determining least significant predictor in Linear Regression Model with R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have to create a good model with linear regression using a subset named psub

I created a population for test and a population for training :

```
nobs <- nrow(psub)
set.seed(1000)
train_indices <- sample(1:nobs, 0.7*nobs, replace=F)
test_indices <- setdiff(1: nobs, train_indices)
a <- psub.train <- psub[train_indices,]
psub.train <- psub[train_indices,]
psub.test <- psub[test_indices,]
psub.train <- psub%>%sample_frac(0.70, replace = FALSE)
psub.test <- setdiff(psub, psub.train)
```

I created a model :

```
psub.model = lm(PINCP ~ SEX*AGEP*COW*SCHL, data = psub.train)
```

Now, I want to know which predictor or which combination of predictors is the least significant without having to look through every p-value of the summary(psub.model)

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Well, you can look at the p-values, or you can perform automated variable selection. Ridge/lasso regression might be applicable, but this is a really broad question, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the max value of the vector of p-values (corresponding to the least significant predictor) should work something like this ...

```
cc <- coef(summary(psub.model))  ## coefficient table
which.max(cc[,"Pr(>|t|)"])
```

Answer (score 4):

[This is not a good way of doing model selection](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/). But if you want to do it, it sounds like what you're looking for is [stepwise regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepwise_regression), specifically backwards elimination. Stepwise selection is covered in many textbooks, like [this one](http://health.adelaide.edu.au/psychology/ccs/teaching/lsr/).

A code example:

```
#predict iris petal length from the other variables
#begin by fitting full model
full_model = lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Species, data = iris)

#backwards elimination
step(full_model, direction = "backward")
```

This returns the best fitting model according to AIC, in this case this was the full model.

Comment: If you are doing backward elimination then why do you start with a combination of your parameters using + and not *?

Comment: Reasonable question, but IMO it's an open question whether you would always want to include all interactions in the full model ...

Comment: Thank you it really helped me. I validated the other answer because it was exactly what I was looking for, but your answer is really helpful.

Comment: In general, stepwise regression does not work well because it leads to overfitted models. Including interactions makes the problem worse.